# Floating action menu icon is never set

Tags: android

Im using the following code to add Floating  action menu .

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_fab_star"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">
```

The problem is that , the icon is never set. How to set icon to a floating action menu?

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using does not allow changing the icon of `FloatingActionsMenu`. See [this](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/issues/242) issue on github. Only `FloatingActionButton` icon can be changed. There is a fork of the same project [here](https://github.com/boxlady/android-floating-action-button) with capability of changing the icon.

Comment: i have added the dependency. what is the tag that i should use to change?

Comment: You have to download the library and add it to your project manually.

Comment: I have done it. what is the xml tag that I should use to change the icon of floating menu?

Comment: `fab:menu_icon="@drawable/your_icon"`

Comment: Error:(19) No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu_icon' in package  is the error being thrown

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/boxlady/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml), the creator of library used it that way.

Comment: any ideas  on how i can fix it?

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) library. I am guessing you want something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XngUY3PN1IQ&feature=youtu.be&t=34s).